# Angular 1.5. Getting ngModelControllers under ng-if/ng-switch inside a form level directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm building a form level directive which has to access all child ngModelControllers. Using `querySelectorAll('[ng-model]')` in link phase works fine for all ngModelControllers except for the ones under `ng-if` and `ng-switch` blocks which are ignored probably since they are not visible during the link/controller phase of the form level directive.

So far I've come up with two possible solutions neither of which I like:

1. Set an interval which would every xy seconds get all ngModelControllers again and check for the differences with the already stored controllers.
2. Replace all `ng-if` and `ng-switch` directives with `ng-show`

My question is, is there something I can do to either somehow get those invisible ngModelControllers, or hook into `FormController`'s `addControl` function and use that to add ngModelControllers to my directive since `FormController` doesn't seem to have any issues with ngModels within `ng-if` and `ng-switch` directives?

Below is a snippet demonstrating my issue. In HTML view there are 6 inputs visible, but only 4 are visible in the array. The missing two are under `ng-if` and `ng-switch`.

```js
(function(){
  angular.module('test', []);
  angular.module('test')
    .controller('MainController', MainController)
    .directive('modelGatherer', modelGatherer)
    .directive('gatheredModelDisplay', gatheredModelDisplay);
  
  MainController.$inject = [];
  
  function MainController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.displayed = true;
  }
  
  function modelGatherer() {
    modelGathererController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    
    function modelGathererController($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.ngModels = [];
      
      vm.addModel = addModel;
      
      //
      function addModel(model) {
        if(angular.isDefined(model)) {          
          vm.ngModels.push(model);
        }
      }
    }
    
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      require: 'modelGatherer',
      controller: modelGathererController,
      priority: 5000,
      link: link
    };
    
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {      
      
      var ngModelElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].querySelectorAll('[ng-model]'));                 
      
      ngModelElements
      .map(toNgModelController)
      .forEach(addToCtrl);
      
      
      //
      function toNgModelController(val) {
        return angular.element(val).controller('ngModel');          
      }
      
      function addToCtrl(val) {
        ctrl.addModel(val);
      }
    }
  }
  
  function gatheredModelDisplay() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^modelGatherer',
      template: '<pre>{{ctrlNames | json}}</pre>',
      scope: true,
      link: link
    };
    
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.ctrlNames = [];
      
      scope.$watch(getNgModelCtrls, onNgModelCtrlChange, true);
      
      //
      function getNgModelCtrls() {
        return ctrl.ngModels;
      }
      
      function onNgModelCtrlChange(newVal) {
        scope.ctrlNames = newVal.map(toName);
        
        //
        function toName(val) {
          return val.$name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <form no-validate model-gatherer>    
    <input type="text" name="test1" placeholder="test1" ng-model="main.test1" />
    <input type="text" name="test2" placeholder="test2" ng-model="main.test2" />
    <input type="text" name="test3" placeholder="test3" ng-model="main.test3" />
    <div ng-if="main.displayed">
      <input type="text" name="test4" placeholder="test4" ng-model="main.test4" />
    </div>    
    <div ng-switch="main.displayed">
      <input ng-switch-when="true" type="text" name="test5" placeholder="test5" ng-model="main.test5" />
    </div>
    <div ng-show="main.displayed">      
      <input type="text" name="test6" placeholder="test6" ng-model="main.test6" />
    </div>
    <gathered-model-display />
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about switching it up. Instead of the model-gatherer gathering the inputs, have the inputs register themselves with the model-gatherer. For example by adding another directive on the inputs and doing this in the link function.

Comment: @Piittis Indeed that is a possibility and if I were developing a project from scratch that's how I would go about doing it, however, on the project where I'm planning on implementing remote validation using a form level directive such as the one in the op, there's a large number of forms and inputs already made which makes adding directives to inputs a tedious and long procedure.